# Camera Reactions aren't turning off

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, camera

I use OBS for MS Teams and Zoom calls and while I am in a meeting, I get the camera reactions. The reactions button is off (grey) for both Facetime and my external camera on the OBS section of the Mac widget at the top of the screen (the purple presenter icon or the green camera icon). I have done and checked this while each app is running. Yet all reactions trigger with the correct action on screen.

Have read this: [How can I disable sending 'Reactions' that appear during video calls that I join from macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/468003/how-can-i-disable-sending-reactions-that-appear-during-video-calls-that-i-join) But I've turned it off for each application specifically and it is still happening.

After some testing, it looks like the OBS virtual camera might be the device triggering the Reactions. When I enable Reactions on my external camera, I get 2 reactions: one around me and one that fills the "canvas" of the display area. When I disable Reactions, I only get the display area Reaction. If the OBS virtual camera is interpreted as a separate video source, then Reactions would need to be turned off on that camera, but there is no UI to do that (only the external webcam and Facetime).

Is it possible to turn off Reactions processing on the OBS virtual camera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

- Open Teams/Zoom/whatever ***without OBS as the video source***
- Disable reactions making sure that it's Teams/Zoom/whatever where it is being disabled
- Close Teams/Zoom/whatever
- Open Teams/Zoom/whatever and add OBS as the video source

This worked for me.